# Given a domain-controlled group, how can I get its domain?

Tags: group, ldap

I'm working on an application which collects data on groups. In my application I need to collect data and the residing users of local groups and send meta-data on domain-controlled groups.

My problem is, given such remote group (using `getent group groupName`) how can I determine its domain?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `winbind` to authenticate with your AD domain, then you can use the `wbinfo` command to get this information:

To list all domain groups:

```
$ wbinfo --domain-groups
unix_group1
unix_group2
DOM2+windows_group1
DOM2+windows_group2
DOM3+windows_group3
```

This option will list all groups available in the Windows domain for which your host is operating in.
Some groups are listed with the preceeding domain name (`DOM2+`). The ones without a domain name are from the local domain.

To establish the hosts own domain to which it belongs:

```
$ wbinfo --own-domain
DOM1
```

To list all domains that the hosts `samba` daemon is operating in:

```
$ wbinfo --domain-groups
DOM1
DOM2
DOM3
```

To confirm the group membership, you can set the domain to search in then check for domain groups:

```
$ wbinfo --domain DOM1 --domain-groups | grep unix
unix_group1
unix_group2
```

Comment: I can't guarantee that I'm using winbind.
I need to make it work on any machine...
Good answer though.

Comment: @Tom sorry that I got the bounty without providing the full solution. Following your comment, I did test out all the `net ads group` type comnbinations to try to get the answer for you that way, however, I could not get a viable solution to providing the domain for each group. Good luck...